# How do I click on a radio button that is really a div

Tags: javascript, primefaces

My company is using Primefaces JS framework. I'm trying to use WebDriver to click on a Yes radio button. But its not a conventional radio button.

Here is the code and I'm not sure how to formulate the WD statement .click() action?

```
<td class="ui-panelgrid-cell nc4ui-logistics-values-left" role="gridcell">
<div id="A0588:search-panels:governmentProperty" class="ui-selectonebutton ui-buttonset ui-widget ui-corner-all boolean-value">
<div class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left">
<input id="A0588:search-panels:governmentProperty:0" class="ui-helper-hidden" type="radio" onchange="nc4uiLogisticsChanged();" value="Yes" name="A0588:search-panels:governmentProperty">
<span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Yes</span>
</div>
<div class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-right ui-state-active">
</div>
</td>
<td class="ui-panelgrid-cell nc4ui-logistics-labels" role="gridcell">
<td class="ui-panelgrid-cell nc4ui-logistics-values-right" role="gridcell">
```

I've tried the following with no success:

```
ele = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("aui_3_4_0_1_1659")));
    ele.click();

    ele = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'aui_3_4_0_1')]")));
    ele.click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'aui_3_4_0_1')]")).click();
```

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0):

Where is the id "aui_3_4_0_1_1659" in your HTML? Can´t find it.... The id of the radio button in the HTML is this one "A0588:search-panels:governmentProperty:0". Maybe is that the issue?

Comment: The id "aui_3_4_0_1_1659" I've sent discovered is generated on the fly after you click on the Yes part of the so-called radio button. So, when the page initially loads, that id is not present. So, its too late to use it as I was trying to do (obviously why it wasn't working).

I tried A0588:search-panels:governmentProperty:0 but it didn't work either.

Comment: Could you use jQuery to select and click on the element? Would be a lot easier than using xpath. Also, if helps, I did use [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/) for scrapping, which runs on top of phantomjs, and for some elements, the .click() event was not firing. I had to inject JS and use jQuery which is cross-browser. Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4u67uxe/) with your HTML but using using jQuery instead.

Comment: No we're not using jquery. I did find out that this tricky HTML is coded without using the normal radio tag. I was told that what I need to do is use css and try to detect if the class 'ui-state-active' is present in that div following the div id= -- I've been trying to write the css but so far have not been able to get it right. What makes this complex is that the class=ui-state-active is elsewhere on the web page so I have to combine it with that id=A0588  to narrow it down to the right so called radio button.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally ended up that worked:

ele = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id$=governmentProperty] div:not(.ui-state-active) span.ui-button-text"));